# How to get acroFields from a PDF page(iText)?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader, acrofields

How can I get the acroFields from a specific page in PDF file using iText?
More exactly using the package **com.lowagie.text.pdf**.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
if(pages > 0)
{
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= pages ; i++)
    {
        //get page i from reader
        //get acroFields for that page
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are using a package with my name in it. Yes, I am Bruno Lowagie, the original developer of the software you are using. I would like to ask you to upgrade to the latest iText version. The version that you are using is at least 7 years old. It has been declared *End-of-Life* years ago. It is no longer supported and [it should no longer be used in a business context](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: It is a pleasure to meet you :). I heard this version of iText is very old, but for some reasons I can't use the new version of Itext :(. So, is there a solution for getting the acroFields for a specific page using this version :(?

Comment: There may be "some reasons" but none of them can be any good.